# Implementing Stack with Python

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, stack

I am trying to implement a simple stack with Python using arrays. I was wondering if someone could let me know what's wrong with my code.

```
class myStack:
     def __init__(self):
         self = []

     def isEmpty(self):
         return self == []

     def push(self, item):
         self.append(item)

     def pop(self):
         return self.pop(0)

     def size(self):
         return len(self)

    s = myStack()
    s.push('1')
    s.push('2')
    print(s.pop())
    print s
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-stacks

Comment: Even if your code manages to turn your object into a list, wouldn't this mean that you loose all your custom methods?

Comment: It should be just pop() not pop(0). pop(0) makes it a queue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I corrected a few problems below.  Also, a 'stack', in abstract programming terms, is usually a collection where you add and remove from the top, but the way you implemented it, you're adding to the top and removing from the bottom, which makes it a queue.

```
class myStack:
     def __init__(self):
         self.container = []  # You don't want to assign [] to self - when you do that, you're just assigning to a new local variable called `self`.  You want your stack to *have* a list, not *be* a list.

     def isEmpty(self):
         return self.size() == 0   # While there's nothing wrong with self.container == [], there is a builtin function for that purpose, so we may as well use it.  And while we're at it, it's often nice to use your own internal functions, so behavior is more consistent.

     def push(self, item):
         self.container.append(item)  # appending to the *container*, not the instance itself.

     def pop(self):
         return self.container.pop()  # pop from the container, this was fixed from the old version which was wrong

     def peek(self):
         if self.isEmpty():
             raise Exception("Stack empty!")
         return self.container[-1]  # View element at top of the stack

     def size(self):
         return len(self.container)  # length of the container

     def show(self):
         return self.container  # display the entire stack as list


s = myStack()
s.push('1')
s.push('2')
print(s.pop())
print(s.show())
```

Comment: To make it a stack, the pop function should be
`def pop(self): return self.container.pop(-1)`

Comment: @Sanju or just `self.container.pop()`.

Comment: why does the last print output "<__main__.myStack object at 0x006C39D0>" ?

Comment: AttributeError: 'Stack' object has no attribute 'stack' .. check your `show(self)` function

Comment: `self.size()` does not work. It should either be `self.container == []` or `len(self.container) == 0`

Comment: @EnisArik Works for me - what error or unexpected behavior are you getting?

Comment: @Brionius, ah it is my bad! I did not include the `size` method :) That was the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Assigning to `self` won't turn your object into a list (and if it did, the object wouldn't have all your stack methods any more). Assigning to `self` just changes a local variable. Instead, set an attribute:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.stack = []
```

and use the attribute instead of just a bare `self`:

```
def push(self, item):
    self.stack.append(item)
```

Also, if you want a stack, you want `pop()` rather than `pop(0)`. `pop(0)` would turn your data structure into a(n inefficient) queue.

Answer (score 3):

A stack is a container (linear collection) in which dynamic set operations
are carried out as per the last-in first-out (LIFO) principle.
There is only one pointer - `top`, which is used to perform these operations

CLRS implementation of stack using array:

```
class Stack:
    """
    Last in first out (LIFO) stack implemented using array.
    """
    def __init__(self, capacity=4):
        """
        Initialize an empty stack array with default capacity of 4.
        """
        self.data = [None] * capacity
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.top  = -1

    def is_empty(self):
        """
        Return true if the size of stack is zero.
        """
        if self.top == -1:
            return True
        return False

    def push(self, element):
        """
        Add element to the top.
        """
        self.top += 1
        if self.top >= self.capacity:
            raise IndexError('Stack overflow!')
        else:
            self.data[self.top] = element

    def pop(self):
        """
        Return and remove element from the top.
        """
        if self.is_empty():
            raise Exception('Stack underflow!')
        else:
            stack_top = self.data[self.top]
            self.top -= 1
            return stack_top

    def peek(self):
        """
        Return element at the top.
        """
        if self.is_empty():
            raise Exception('Stack is empty.')
            return None
        return self.data[self.top]

    def size(self):
        """
        Return the number of items present.
        """
        return self.top + 1
```

Testing the implemetation:

```
def main():
    """
    Sanity test
    """
    stack = Stack()

    print('Size of the stack is:', stack.size())
    stack.push(3)
    print('Element at the top of the stack is: ', stack.peek())
    stack.push(901)
    print('Element at the top of the stack is: ', stack.peek())
    stack.push(43)
    print('Element at the top of the stack is: ', stack.peek())
    print('Size of the stack is:', stack.size())
    stack.push(89)
    print('Element at the top of the stack is: ', stack.peek())
    print('Size of the stack is:', stack.size())
    #stack.push(9)    # Raises IndexError
    stack.pop()
    print('Size of the stack is:', stack.size())
    stack.pop()
    print('Size of the stack is:', stack.size())
    stack.pop()
    print('Size of the stack is:', stack.size())
    print('Element at the top of the stack is: ', stack.peek())
    stack.pop()
    #print('Element at the top of the stack is: ', stack.peek())    # Raises empty stack exception

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

I left a comment with the link to http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-stacks, but if you want to have a custom type that gives you `push`, `pop`, `is_empty`, and `size` convenience methods, I'd just subclass `list`.

```
class Stack(list):
    def push(self, item):
        self.append(item)
    def size(self):
        return len(self)
    def is_empty(self):
        return not self
```

However, as I said in the comments, I'd probably just stick with a straight `list` here, as all you are really doing is aliasing existing methods, which usually only serves to make your code harder to use in the long run, as it requires people using it to learn your aliased interface on top of the original.

Comment: `is_empty` should return `not self`. Of course, doing this at all is probably a bad idea; it's trying to make the Python collection interfaces look like some other language.

Comment: My mistake on the `is_empty` thing, I fixed that.  As to your other point, I'd agree that you should probably just use the standard list interface in this case, but creating a subclass to implement an additional interface on an existing type is entirely reasonable, if you have legitimate need.

Comment: how would you define pop? pop(self, item) : self.pop(item)?

Comment: You don't need to, because `list` already has a `pop` that works exactly as you need it to without any arguments.

Comment: You really should just use the `list` interface directly though, unless you need to have the aliased method names for some sort of homework assignment.

Comment: That’s what I too felt..everything the code does is already available as methods in List in python.. more info on how to use list as stack is available in the documentation                                    https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 1):

The proper implementation would include `__iter__` also since Stack needs to be LIFO order.

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self._a = []

    def push(self, item):
        self._a.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self._a.pop()

    def isEmpty(self):
        return len(self._a) == 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return reversed(self._a)

    def __str__(self):
        # return str(list(reversed(self._a)))
        return str(list(iter(self)))

def main():
    stack = Stack()
    stack.push('a')
    stack.push('b')
    stack.push('c')
    stack.pop()
    print(stack)
    if stack:
        print("stack not empty")
    stack.pop()
    stack.pop()
    if stack.isEmpty():
        print("stack empty")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're popping from the beginning of the list, when you should be popping from the end of the list. A stack is a Last-In First-Out data structure, meaning that when you pop something from it, that something will be whatever you pushed on last. Take a look at your push function - it appends an item to the list. That means that it goes at the end of the list. When you call .pop(0), however, you're removing the first item in the list, not the one you last appended. Removing the 0 from .pop(0) should solve your problem.

Comment: That's not the main problem. The bigger issue is trying to assign to `self`.

Answer (score 0):

Your stack is an array...

```
class stacked(): # Nodes in the stack
    def __init__(self,obj,next):
        self.obj = obj
        self.next = next
    def getObj(self):
        return(self.obj)
    def getNext(self):
        return(self.next)

class stack(): # The stack itself
    def __init__(self):
        self.top=None
    def push(self,obj):
        self.top = stacked(obj,self.top)
    def pop(self):
        if(self.top == None):
            return(None)
        r = self.top.getObj()
        self.top = self.top.getNext()
        return(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the simple implementation of stack in python. In addition, it returns the middle element at any point in time.

```
  class Stack:
        def __init__(self):
            self.arrList = []

        def isEmpty(self):
            if len(self.arrList):
                return False
            else:
                return True

        def push(self, val):
            self.arrList.append(val)

        def pop(self):
            if not self.isEmpty():
                self.arrList[len(self.arrList)-1]
                self.arrList = self.arrList[:len(self.arrList)-1]
            else:
                print "Stack is empty"

        def returnMiddle(self):
            if not self.isEmpty():
                mid = len(self.arrList)/2
                return self.arrList[mid]
            else:
                print "Stack is empty"

        def listStack(self):
            print self.arrList

    s = Stack()
    s.push(5)
    s.push(6)
    s.listStack()
    print s.returnMiddle()
    s.pop()
    s.listStack()
    s.push(20)
    s.push(45)
    s.push(435)
    s.push(35)
    s.listStack()
    print s.returnMiddle()
    s.pop()
    s.listStack()
```

Output:

```
[5, 6]
6
[5]
[5, 20, 45, 435, 35]
45
[5, 20, 45, 435]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Implementing a Stack in Python](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/BasicDS/ImplementingaStackinPython.html) from the book of Problem Solving with Algorithms and Data Structures

Answer (score 0):

Below is my implementation

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = list()
    def is_empty(self):
        return self.items == []
    def peek(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            print('Cannot peek empty stack')
            return
        else:
            return self.items[-1]
    def pop(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            print('Cannot pop an empty stack')
            return
        else:
            return self.items.pop()
    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)
    def push(self,data):
        self.items.append(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share my version of the stack implementation that inherits Python List. I believe iteration on a stack should be happening in LIFO order. Additionally, an iteration on `pop-all()` should be provided to iterate while poping all elements. I have also added `stack.clear()` to empty a stack (like we have in [`deque.clear()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque.clear) in collections module). I have also override `__repr__` for debugging purpose:

```
class Stack(list):

    def push(self, item):
        self.append(item)

    def top(self):
        return self[-1]

    def size(self):
        return len(self)

    def isempty(self):
        return self.size() == 0

    def __iter__(self):
        """ iter in lifo """
        return super(Stack, self).__reversed__()

    def __reversed__(self):
        return super(Stack, self).__iter__()

    def popall(self):
        try:
            while True:
                yield self.pop()
        except IndexError:
            pass

    def clear(self):
        del self[:]

    def __repr__(self):
        if not self:
            return '%s()' % self.__class__.__name__
        return '%s(%s)' % (self.__class__.__name__, super(Stack, self).__repr__())
```

Here is how you can use it:

```
stack = Stack(range(5))
print "stack: ", stack  # stack:  Stack([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

print "stack.pop() => ", stack.pop() # stack.pop() =>  4
print "stack.push(20) " # stack.push(20) 
stack.push(20)
for item in stack:
    print item  # prints 20, 3, 2... in newline
print "stack: ", stack # stack:  Stack([0, 1, 2, 3, 20])
print "stack pop all..."
for item in stack.popall(): # side effect to clear stack
    print item
print "stack: ", stack # stack:  Stack()
```

Primary, I implemented it to use to solve a programming problem [next greater element](https://github.com/Grijesh-Chauhan/Interviews/tree/master/Puzzles/NGE).

Answer (score -2):

```
class Stack:
   s =[]

   def push(self, num):
       self.s.append(num)

   def pop(self):
       if len(self.s) == 0: # erro if you pop an empty list
           return -1
       self.s.remove(self.s[-1])

   def isEmpty(self):
       if len(self.s) == 0:
           return True
       else:
           return False

   def display(self): # this is to display how a stack actually looks like
       if self.isEmpty():
           print("Stack is Empty")
    
       for i in range(len(self.s)-1,-1,-1): # I haven't used reversed() since it will be obv
           print(self.s[i])


obj = Stack()
obj.push(3)
print(obj.isEmpty())
obj.push(4)
obj.display()
print("----")
obj.pop()
obj.display()
```