# How to implement stack in python?

Tags: python, data-structures, stack

This problem may use the concept of stack in python.
My code is as follows, but it always get Time Limit Exceed (TLE) error.
I think the problem is the algorithm I design is too slow due to two loops.
I would like to know how to implement the concept of stack and use only one loop in this problem. Please instruct me and help me to revise the code, thank you so much.

**Input: including one line, which contains several integers, representing the score of each time, and the numbers are separated by spaces**

**Output: including one line, which contains several integers, representing the interval frequency when increase happens of each score(if the score does not increase, it returns 0), and the numbers are separated by spaces**

```
inp = [int(i) for i in input().split()]

#create a function to calculate intervals
def cal_interval(lst):
    lenth = len(inp)
    output_lst = []
    for i in range(lenth):
        #set counter 
        count = 1

        #set iteraion number
        iter_num = 0
        for j in range(i+1, lenth):
            iter_num += 1
            if inp[j] > inp[i]:
                output_lst.append(count)
                break
            else:
                count += 1
                if iter_num == (lenth-i-1):
                    output_lst.append(0)
                    break
    #last number
    output_lst.append(0)
    #from int list transformed into str list
    output_lst = [str(i) for i in output_lst]
    #join by spaces
    space = ' '
    interval_str = space.join(output_lst)
    return interval_str

print (cal_interval(inp))
```

there are two sets of test data as follows,

```
Sample Input 1: 89 56 78 9 81 7
Sample Output 1: 0 1 2 1 0 0
Sample Input 2: 76 3 60 57 11 72 73 86 27 91 56 58 21 2
Sample Output 2: 7 1 3 2 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 0 0 0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implementing Stack with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18279775/implementing-stack-with-python)

Comment: Look at [collections.deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque). As stated in docs: Deques are a generalization of stacks and queues

Comment: Why is the second output not: `0 1 0 0 ...`?

Comment: My explanation as follows,
For 76, there are 7 intervals to reach 86, which is higher than 76. For 3, there is only 1 interval to reach 60, which is higher than 3. For 60, there are 3 intervals to reach 72, which is higher than 3.So on and so forth...

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do this using slicing with some comprehensions, also `next` will be useful as you can supply it a default:

```
def get_intervals(data):
    for score, *nums in (data[i:] for i in range(len(data))):
        yield next((i for i, n in enumerate(nums, 1) if n > score), 0)
```

All I’m doing here is each iteration, `score` is the next number in data and `nums` is the rest after it. Then using next it’s grabbing the first value’s index in nums if the value is above score otherwise defaulting to `0`.

So with that all you need to do in place of `cal_interval` is print the result of `get_intervals` joined:

```
print(' '.join(get_intervals([89, 56, 78, 9, 81, 7])))
print(' '.join(get_intervals( [76, 3, 60, 57, 11, 72, 73, 86, 27, 91, 56, 58, 21, 2])))
```

Results:

```
0 1 2 1 0 0
7 1 3 2 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 0 0 0
```

Comment: Really thank you. I try your code but still get Time Limit Exceed (TLE) error. I think the problem is that your answer still contains two loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
def stack():
    while(f==1):
        print("1. Push\n2. Pop\n3. Peek\n4. Traverse\n5. Quit")
        print("Enter any input: ")
        a = input()
        if a != '':
            a = int(a)
        switch(a)

def switch(a):
    global top
    if a == 1:
        print("Enter the Element To push")
        b = input()
        print(top)
        top += 1
        ar.append(b)
        print(b,"item was Pushed")
    elif a == 2:
        poped()
        print("item was Poped")
    elif a == 3:
        c = ar[top]
        print("Peek value is:",c)
    elif a == 4:
        print("Traversing all items")
        for i in ar:
            print(i)
    elif a ==5:
        print("Quit")
        global f
        f=2
    else:
        print("Invalid Value")


def poped():
    if top == -1:
        print("Stack is Empty /  Pop not performed")
    else:
        ar.pop()
        top -= 1

# Driver Code
f = 1
top = -1
ar = []
stack()
```